# Calculate the $E[X]$ for the density function of $\frac{xe^{-\frac{x}{2}}}{4}$

Tags: mathematical-statistics, density-function

I'm trying to compute the $E[X]$ if $X$ has a density function given by:

$$\left[\frac{xe^{-\frac{x}{2}}}{4}\right]    x>0  \space otherwise  \space 0$$

How I approached it:

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{4}\int_{0}^{1}x^2e^{-\frac{x}{2}}dx$$

Integrating by parts:
$u = x^2$; $dv = e^{-\frac{x}{2}}$; $v = -\frac{1}{2}e^{-\frac{x}{2}}$

$$-\frac{x^2e^{-\frac{x}{2}}}{8}|_{0}^{1} \space + \frac{1}{4}\int_{0}^{1}xe^{-\frac{x}{2}}dx$$
Further integration by parts:

$$-\frac{xe^{-\frac{x}{2}}}{8}|_{0}^{1}+\frac{1}{8}\int_{0}^{1}e^{-\frac{x}{2}} dx$$

$$-\frac{x^2e^{-\frac{x}{2}}}{8}|_{0}^{1}-\frac{xe^{-\frac{x}{2}}}{8}|_{0}^{1}-\frac{e^{-\frac{x}{2}}}{16}|_{0}^{1}$$

I have gone wrong somewhere and I think it may be the boundary conditions, so I would really appreciate some support on my approach!

Comment: The boundary condition is $x>0$. So instead of $\int _0^1$, $\int_0^\infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is right, however, the boundary condition should be $(0, \infty)$. $$E(X)=\frac 14\int_0^\infty x^2e^{-\frac x2}dx$$

Letting $u=x^2,du=2xdx,dv=e^{-\frac x2}dx,v=-2e^{-\frac x2}$, we have

$$E(X)=\frac 14\left[-2x^2e^{-\frac x2}\big|_0^\infty+4\int_0^\infty x e^{-\frac x 2}dx\right]$$

Again letting $u=x, du=dx,dv=e^{-\frac x2}dx, v=-2e^{-\frac x2}$, we get

$$\begin{split}E(X)&=\frac 14\left[0+4\left(-2xe^{-\frac x2}\big|_0^\infty+2\int_0^\infty e^{-\frac x2}dx\right)\right]\\
&=\frac 1 4\left[4\left(0+2(-2)e^{-\frac x2}\big|_0^\infty\right)\right]\\
&=-4(0-1)\\
&=4\end{split}$$

Further this is $\text{Gamma}\left(2, \frac 12\right)$ with expected value $\frac \alpha\beta=\frac 2 {\frac 12}=4$ as a check.

Comment: Thanks for showing me the correct approach as I know see that I completely messed up with the substitution for x in the exponential